# Sending a file and some string value in single post request using angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-directive

I am trying to upload an image to the server along with that I am sending a string value through $ upload post method. Some how I am able to process the requested file through the $upload method. I dont know how to access the string data that I send through this post request.Here is my controller code

```
 $scope.string1="abcd";
            createFile = $scope.files.slice(0);
            console.log(createFile);
            console.log("upload function");
            if (createFile) { // console.log(file.name);
                $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                    url: '/uploadResortsImage', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        myObj: $scope.myModelObj,
                        $scope.dataone:$scope.string1,
                    },
                    file: createFile, // or list of files ($files) for html5 only
                    //  fileName: this.name +'.pdf', //or ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', ...] // to modify the name of the file(s)
                })
```

My appliaction stack is meanjs and Here goes my server code.

```
exports.upload = function (req, res) {
    console.log("upload function");
    console.log(req);
    var filename = '',
        target_path = '';
    console.log(req.files);
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log(files.file);
        var tmp_path = files.file.path;
        var tmp_path_string = String(tmp_path);
        console.log(tmp_path_string);
        filename = files.file.name;
        var dir = "./public/uploads";
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        var dir1 = dir + '/' + resortid;
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir1)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir1);
        }
        var dest_path = dir1 + "/";
        target_path = dest_path + filename;
        console.log(dest_path);
        console.log(filename);
        console.log(target_path);
        var target_path_string = String(target_path);
        fs.rename(tmp_path_string, target_path_string, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                console.log("fail");
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("successful");
                done(err, resort);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you need

```
                data: {
                    myObj: $scope.myModelObj,
                    myObjB: $scope.string1,
                },
```

Then on the server side, you would just access that myObjB property or whatever you decide to call it in the incoming form values collection depending on what your are using server side. Using $scope.dataone as a property name in your data object doesn't make sense as that's a scope property from elsewhere in your AngularJS code, stick to simple property names.

Comment: I am using the nodejs in the server side.Here is my code

Comment: Thanks. I have added my serve code. Let me conform that I understood properly how to access that myObjB. Is it correct to add a parameter called string1 in the form.parse() method in the server code or is there any other way to access it.

Comment: If you but a break point in the server side code on console.log(req) what does require look like in the debugger?

Comment: I am trying to console log the req.body.data but it is undefined. Can you please answer me with more info. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I meant what does the req look like in the debugger if you break in console.log(req)?

Answer (score 0):

I was using formidabble plug in the node application.My code goes like this and I am able to access the send data objects in the server side.

```
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
var data_received= fields.myObjB;
}
```

Thanks.